# iPad app with multiple UIWebViews in the same screen

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

does it hurt performance to have multiple UIWebViews in the same screen? how do I use a busy indicator while the web page is loading and display the fully loaded page once all contents have been downloaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two UIWebViews will take twice the time to render on screen. If this is a problem depends on your app and your content. Just try it.

To implement your busy indicator you could implement a delegate for your WebViews. see [UIWebViewDelegate-Protocol](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIWebViewDelegate)